# Another double subscript problem

Tags: amsmath, subscripts

I obtained following correct formula via https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

[image]

The formula is written as follows:

```
$L_{im}:=(L_{1m},L_{2m},...,L_{(N+1)^{K_{m}}}_{,m})^T$ $(m=1,2,...,M_{max})$
```

but after copy and paste procedure, I get following error message:

```
Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \atop;
(amsmath) \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath) on input line 101.
! Double subscript.
l.116 ...:=(L_{1m},L_{2m},...,L_{{(N+1)}^{K_{m}}}_
{,m})^T$ $(m=1,2,...,M_{ma...
```

I treat `x_1_2` essentially like `x_1{}_2`.

Comment: @egreg We edited at the same time.

Comment: The formula you got is surely *not* correct.

Comment: Your last assumption is essentially the issue, since `x_1_2` is not allowed.

Comment: As far as I can see, codecogs doesn't report several types of error in the input. Avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$L_{im}:=(L_{1m},L_{2m},\dots,L_{(N+1)^{K_{m}},m})^T$ $(m=1,2,\dots,M_{\text{max}})$

$A_{a}:=(B_{b}, C_{c}, \dots D_{d1^{d2}, d3})^z$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

- As @Werner already mentioned in his comment, `x_1_2` is not allowed.
- In addition, start with the basic structure of the formula and then fill in the details. I tried to show this in the second equation.
- Maybe the generator you use is not the best. My advice would be to read a LaTeX introduction and do it by hand.
- I used `\text` to typeset upright labels. [@David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090) points out that he would recommend using `\mathrm` though.

Comment: `...` should be `\dots` and `max` in the subscript should be upright.

Comment: @egreg Yes. I just started and tried to find the error.

Comment: there us still a `...` and I'd use `\mathrm` rather than `\text`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes yes :). I am working on it. I am not as fast as you guys :). I prefer `\text` because it respects spaces and so on. But I do not think that this is very important in this case (question).

Comment: Ich bedanke mich für Ihren  Hilfe! @Dr.ManuelKuehner

Comment: @egreg Done - now you can upvote.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done - now you can upvote.

Comment: `\text` is a lot less efficient (sets its content four times) can produce worse spacing (it's a box so loses any font level italic correction information) and crucially doesn't give a fixed font so would give an italic _max_ in an italic context such as a theorem. (actually I voted but neither of the things I mentioned are done)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not sure I can follow your comment. Maybe we have a misunderstanding. I replaced the last missing `... --> \ldots`. If you are still unhappy then feel free to edit my question or down vote. I am preparing a presentation for a conference at the moment and was just a bit procrastinating :). You know that I am not an expert...

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner no I'll leave it, but `\text` is still basically the wrong command here. Thanks for fixing the  `...`